# Is a class being instantiated in a lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-interface

I have the following method invocation, in which I am passing a lambda expression. Is a class being instantiated implicitly here?

```
printStudents(
    roster,
    (Student s) -> s.getGender() == Student.Sex.MALE
        && s.getAge() >= 18
        && s.getAge() <= 25
);
```

Method signature:

```
printStudents(List<Student> roster, CheckStudent checkstudet)
```

```
interface CheckStudent {
    boolean test(Student s);
}
```

**Edit**

Some of you suggested me to refactor the code, but the same question arises.

```
CheckStudent checkStudent = (Student s) -> s.getGender() == Student.Sex.MALE && s.getAge() >= 18 && s.getAge() <= 25;
```

Is a class (I am not referring to class `Student` ) being instantiated on the right side of the assignment?

Comment: You mean a `class` that `implements` the SMI or `Student`?

Comment: http://www.lambdafaq.org/are-lambda-expressions-objects/

Comment: @BoristheSpider i mean a class the implements CheckStudent - it is a functional interface

Comment: Of course, it might be clearer if you can refactor `(Student s) -> s.getGender() == Student.Sex.MALE && s.getAge() >= 18 && s.getAge() <= 25` by introducing a local variable of class `CheckStudent` similar to `CheckStudent checkStudent = (Student s) -> s.getGender() == Student.Sex.MALE && s.getAge() >= 18 && s.getAge() <= 25;`

Comment: This should answer your question https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The value of a lambda expression is a reference to an instance of a class**. So, in practical terms, yes, an instance of a class is being created. See what the docs say:

> At run time, evaluation of a lambda expression is similar to
> evaluation of a class instance creation expression, insofar as normal
> completion produces a reference to an object.

However, there is more to that than we can "see". There are many optimizations running under the hood. Depending on certain factors, a previously created object can, for example, be used again. This means that **a new object need not be allocated on every evaluation of a lambda expression**. Let's take a look at the docs:

> Evaluation of a lambda expression is distinct from execution of the
> lambda body. Either a new instance of a class with the properties below is
> allocated and initialized, or an existing instance of a class with the
> properties below is referenced.
>
> [...]
>
> These rules are meant to offer flexibility to implementations of the
> Java programming language, in that:
>
> - A new object need not be allocated on every evaluation.
> - Objects produced by different lambda expressions need not belong to different classes (if the bodies are identical, for example).
> - Every object produced by evaluation need not belong to the same class (captured local variables might be inlined, for example).
> - If an "existing instance" is available, it need not have been created at a previous lambda evaluation (it might have been allocated
>   during the enclosing class's initialization, for example).

As you might have noticed, this is a complex topic. For a deeper understanding, take a look at the *The Java® Language Specification, chapter [“15.27.4. Run-time Evaluation of Lambda Expressions”](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.4)*.